# Debian change system timezone to Windows equivalent

Tags: debian, timezone

i'm almost new to linux, so, here is my situation, i have a pc with debian 6 and Webmin 1.570 installed(the easy way), and i want to change the system timezone, i know that in windows server, i'm on

```
(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time(USA & Canada)
```

but i don't see nothing like this in the webmin options, and i'm searching on google, but can't find nothing, so, can someone point me the right timezone for me?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` is the easy interactive way for Debian-based systems.

The manual way, which may be more informative, is something along the lines of `sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/EST5EDT /etc/localtime`

Any of the files in `/usr/share/zoneinfo` will be valid times, often referred to as major cities in different countries. In general, the city closest to you in your country within the same timezone is proper. Anything in the US on the East Coast can be served by the `America/New_York` file.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

and select your timezone.

Comment: I've read that in other webs, but i don't know wich timezone to pick, in windows i know it is `(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time(USA & Canada)` but what is the equivalent in linux??

Comment: @Kstro21 America/New_York

Answer (score 1):

Your timezone settings are handled by your OS.

[Changing the timezone in Debian is done as below](http://wiki.debian.org/TimeZoneChanges).

`dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`

Available time zone files are located at `/usr/share/zoneinfo`

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how to do it with webmin, but here's a workaround.

Log in as root with ssh and type :

```
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

You will be prompted various question about where you live, and if you are lucky, the system will guess the good timezone.